# Failed to deploy my django project on heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku

I was going to deploy my django project on heroku, but I meet the error, I really have no idea how to do, please help, thank you a lot for your checking and answer in advance!

```
 -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
       Traceback (most recent call last):
         File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
           main()
         File "manage.py", line 18, in main
           execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
           utility.execute()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
           self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in run_from_argv
           self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 371, in execute
           output = self.handle(*args, **options)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 194, in handle
           collected = self.collect()
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/management/commands/collectstatic.py", line 109, in collect
           for path, storage in finder.list(self.ignore_patterns):
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py", line 130, in list
           for path in utils.get_files(storage, ignore_patterns):
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/utils.py", line 23, in get_files
           directories, files = storage.listdir(location)
         File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/files/storage.py", line 316, in listdir
           for entry in os.scandir(path):
       FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/build_fa7f7ad1_/static'
 !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
       See traceback above for details.
       You may need to update application code to resolve this error.
       Or, you can disable collectstatic for this application:
          $ heroku config:set DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
 !     Push failed
```

And here is my django project setting.py file: https://github.com/wkeiss/lonelyisland/blob/master/lonelyisland/settings.py

Comment: Could try migrating it once?

Comment: That's not it. The issue is that you are looking for SECRET_KEY in the environment when you haven't set it. Use os.getenv('SECRET_KEY') and set key in your project Settings in Heroku (Settings > Config Vars).

Comment: @TomHamiltonStubber Yep, you're right. I set the key and it fixed the SECRET_KEY  is empty error, thank you a lot! But there is still an error, I has updated it on my question description.

Comment: I found I can run `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput` successfully in my local enviroment. So I set `DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1` in my project Settings in Heroku (Settings > Config Vars), finally the deployment success.

Answer (score 0):

Comment `WhiteNoiseMiddleware`  and try this

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, "staticfiles")
```

Actually worked for me, you can check my setting files [here](https://github.com/mohitchandel/taxi-sevices/blob/master/tuber/settings.py)

Comment: Thank you for answering! Before I got your answer, I found I can run `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput` successfully in my local enviroment. So I tried to set `DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC=1` in my project Settings in Heroku (Settings > Config Vars), finally the deployment success.

Answer (score 0):

STATICFILES_DIRS should contain List not Tuple i think

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
```

so try to chage it like this

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
BASE_DIR / "static",
]
```

Your error is coming because

```
STATIC_URL = '/posts/static/'
```

You have given the URL of the static under the post

But you didn't write that in static_dirs